# android export eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, export, project

I am trying to send an Android Eclipse project to another developer to view and modify. Which is the best way of doing that? I thought it might have something to do with file/export, but I can't work things out. The Eclipse version I'm using is Helios Service Release 2, build id is 20110218-0911

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just zip up the project folders and all sub-folders.  Your recipient can then import that into their eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

Right-click, Export -> General, Archive File -> Next -> provide the output path -> Finish.
Then give this to your developer. He can import it into his workspace.

Comment: I recommend this method because sometimes you don't remember where your workspace. Anyway it looks clear and very straight from the IDE and developer's perspective IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:
  Export->General->File System
and then to a new workspace without any open projects:
  Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most simple if you copy your Android project's map to a pendrive or something and then the developer import it to his/her eclipse. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

run your app in inbuilt emulator. this will result in apk creation somewhere .
locate the path as belows
workspace/**your_app_name**/bin/

there you can find the desired apk file. 
simply copy it where ever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i normally do and it always works:

- Copy the project folder into your Eclipse workspace.
- In Eclipse, File -> Import -> General -> Existing projects in Workspace
- Choose the folder which you just copied into the workspace.

hope it helps